# How to use an Illustrator graphic as a text bullet in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I've created a vector image in Illustrator. I would like to import it into InDesign and use it as bullets.

I googled it but they just mention pasting it on to the clipboard and they don't explain how to do that.

Comment: What they probably mean is the pasteboard, the area outside of your actual page. Just paste and move the object out of your page.

Comment: I've reworded the question title so it is clear what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 16):

You can't actually use them as bullets in the usual sense unless you create a single-glyph font, which you can do using [IndyFont](http://www.indiscripts.com/category/projects/IndyFont) (helpful video and trial download).

If you don't want to buy IndyFont (although I highly recommend it), you can still add a vector from Illustrator to your bullet paragraphs.

- Paste the graphic into InDesign.
- Cut to the clipboard.
- Select the Type tool and click inside the frame where you want to add the graphic.
- Paste.

Your graphic comes in as an inline object and acts much like a glyph, but it's probably in the wrong place.

[image]

- Right click and choose `Anchored Object > Options...`
- Change the Position to "Custom" and select the reference point you want to use (I used the right center, see below).
- Change "X Relative To:" to "Anchor Marker" and adjust the X Offset to whatever you need. (Turn on Preview if it's not already on, so you can see what you're doing.)
- Leave the "Y Relative To:" option at "Line" and adjust the Y Offset.

[image: Custom position]

- As a last step, check "Prevent Manual Positioning" (**Important:** the next bits won't work unless you do this) and click OK.
- Open the Story Editor (`Ctl/Cmd-Y`). Notice the little anchor icon ahead of the text? Select it and copy to the clipboard, then you can close the Story Editor.

[image: Story editor]

- Click at the beginning of each paragraph to which you want to add the shape, and paste. It will come in with all of your settings intact.

[image: Pasted objects]

Answer (score 3):

You can `Edit > Copy` your object from Illustrator, and then `Edit > Paste` it directly into a text frame. The object can then be formatted using many of the same properties as normal text, such as color and spacing. However you'll need to manually re-size it using either the `Selection Tool` or `Free Transform Tool`.

This won't act as an actual bullet though, with true list/paragraph formatting. It's just an easy solution for using custom symbols within text - which will usually get the job done just fine.

However, if you need a more advanced solution for a larger publication, this link has more information on converting a custom symbol into an actual font character:

http://www.lynda.com/articles/indesign-secrets-creating-your-own-custom-bullet-character